# Sending Dataframe from Python to LabVIEW

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, labview

I have a 1 by 400 array in Python. I want to send this output in the format of dataframe (df) to LabVIEW. Is LabVIEW able to receive the array as a dataframe (df)?

Answer (score 0):

A classic way to work with this kind of problems is to store your data in a file, for instance a json file, that is shared across languages.

For instance, you can store your numpy array in a json file. Then, you can open it from Labview. I am not familar with Labview, so I can't help you with how to read data from json, but you can find more information [here](https://forums.ni.com/t5/JSON-Toolkit-for-LabVIEW/JSON-file-I-O/td-p/3386383)

For the numpy part, it looks like this

```
import json
import os
import numpy as np

PATH = "./data/"

toy_data = np.random.random(size=(1,400))

if not os.path.isdir(PATH):
    os.mkdir(PATH)

with open(PATH, "w") as write_file:
    json.dump(toy_data.tolist(), write_file)
```

Comment: In your case, the data seems to be a Dataframe, you can extract the numpy array it contains.

Answer (score 0):

If you have recent (2019 and up) version of LabVIEW, you can use the Python node, call the python function and get the return values of your function.
Alternately, a message/transport library such as 0MQ can connect between the two languages (assuming two processes running simultaneously).
As for Nathan's answer, LabVIEW has JSON libraries that can parse JSON strings.